# pyinstaller: orden no encontrada

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy en ***Ubuntu 18.04*** e intento utilizar pynstaller desde la terminal pero me dice:

> `pyinstaller: orden no encontrada.`

Aunque lo tengo instalado, alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: ¿Lo tienes instalado en el sistema o en un entorno virtual? El comando `which pyinstaller` que es lo que te dice?

Comment: En el sistema.
Si te referis al comando, which halt pyinstaller, me dice esto: /sbin/halt

Comment: No con `which halt pyinstaller` obtienes la ubicación del comando `halt`, digo simplemente `which pyinstaller` para saber si `pyinstaller` lo tienes en `path`.

Comment: Pongo which pyinstaller y no me devuelve nada

Comment: Eso es señal, o que no lo tienes instalado o lo tienes en una ubicación que no está en el path. Usas entornos virtuales con `virtualvenv`?

Comment: Lo instale usando este comando `pip3 install pyinstaller`.
Y no, no uso entornos virtuales.

Comment: Es que sin un entorno virtual, el comando `pip` actua a nivel de la instalación global del sistema, dónde no tienes permisos como usuario común, al menos   sin usar el comando `sudo`. Pero, tealmente te recomiendo que uses `virtualvenv` para crear una instalación local de python en el espacio de usuario y no en el del sistema.

Comment: Bueno, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar de la siguiente manera 
si ya se encuentra instalado busca con el siguiente comando

```
find / -name "pyinstaller"
```

una vez ejecutado ese comando te aparecera la siguiente ruta

```
/usr/local/python3/bin/pyinstaller
```

una vez que haya aparecido esa ruta nos queda pegar el comando para que lo reconozca con el siguiente comando

```
cp /usr/local/python3/bin/pyinstaller /usr/bin/pyinstaller3.cp
```

y listo eso es todo ya te debe funcionar.

Comment: Usando `find / -name "pyinstaller"`
me aparecen muchas cosas con `:permiso denegado`
Uso `sudo find / -name "pyinstaller"`
y me dice: 
`/home/MINOMBREDEUSUARIO/.local/bin/pyinstaller`
intente hacer lo que me dijiste cambiando la ruta que me decis vos con esa que me aparece pero sigo igual.

Comment: pero puedes ejectuarlo con sudo pysintaller ?

Answer (score 0):

A mi me paso igual solo faltaba agregar la ruta a la variable path. asi:

export PATH=$PATH:/tu/ruta/al-archivo